# Visual Studio Cannot Record WebTest

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I'm starting web test record all Web Test Recorder buttons are greyed out. 
Enable and Disable buttons for Web Test Recorder plugin are also grayed out. IE add on are enabled.
Visual Studio was ran as Administrator but issue was not rectified.

Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Version 15.7.3 
Web Test Recorder 15.0

Windows 10 Enterprise
IE version 11.0.105

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q19oi.jpg]

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Please use Snipping tool! Also what is the question?

Comment: How do I get the Web Test Recorder to work and record my steps? Currently, the buttons are all greyed out when i launch it. How do I rectify this?

Comment: Have you tried to use Chrome or other browser?